# ASP.NET MVC 4: error when making Ajax call to controller to update SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, asp.net-ajax

I am attempting to update the records of a table in SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC 4, jQuery and Ajax. However whenever I click update I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
> HResult=-2146232060
> Message=The parameterized query '(@ID int,@AlertStatus nvarchar(4000),@Comment nvarchar(4000))UPD' expects the parameter '@AlertStatus', which was not supplied.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider

On further research I found that this can be avoided by using the `?? DBNull.Value`, however I don't want to update the column to `NULL`. I suspect the reason for the error is in my Ajax call in the update function where the data is not being sent to the controller (data: '{task:' + JSON.stringify(task) + '}',).

Please see the code below and thank you for any assistance.

jQuery Ajax

```
    $("body").on("click", "#tblTask .Edit", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                $(this).find("input").show();
                $(this).find("span").hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Update").show();
        row.find(".Cancel").show();
        row.find(".Delete").hide();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#tblTask .Update", function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                var span = $(this).find("span");
                var input = $(this).find("input");
                span.html(input.val());
                span.show();
                input.hide();
            }
        });
        row.find(".Edit").show();
        row.find(".Delete").hide();
        row.find(".Cancel").hide();
        $(this).hide();

        var task = {};
        task.taskID = row.find(".taskID").find("span").html();
        task.GroupSubsidiary = row.find(".GroupSub").find("span").html();
        task.FunctionName = row.find(".Fname").find("span").html();
        task.FunctionDesc = row.find(".Fdesc").find("span").html();
        task.CheckPeriod = row.find(".Checkp").find("span").html();
        task.Profiledate = row.find(".Pdate").find("span").html();
        task.PeriodDay = row.find(".Pday").find("span").html();
        task.AlertStatus = row.find(".Status").find("span").html();
        task.Comment = row.find(".Comment").find("span").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateTask","Task")",
            data: '{task:' + JSON.stringify(task) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Updated Sucessfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An Error Occured");
            }
        })
    });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTask(Task tasks)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "UPDATE AS_AlertsDefinition SET GroupSubsidiary= @GroupSubsidiary, FunctionName= @FunctionName, FunctionDesc= @FunctionDesc, CheckPeriod= @CheckPeriod, Profiledate= @Profiledate, PeriodDay= @PeriodDay, AlertStatus= @AlertStatus, Comment= @Comment WHERE ID= @ID";

        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", tasks.ID);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupSubsidiary", tasks.GroupSubsidiary);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionName", tasks.FunctionName);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FunctionDesc", tasks.FunctionDesc);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckPeriod", tasks.CheckPeriod);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profiledate", tasks.Profiledate);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeriodDay", tasks.PeriodDay);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlertStatus", tasks.AlertStatus);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", tasks.Comment);
                sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;

                sqlcon.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlcon.Close();
            }
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AlertNotificationWeb.Models
{
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string GroupSubsidiary { get; set; }

    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    public string FunctionDesc { get; set; }

    public string CheckPeriod { get; set; }

    public string Profiledate { get; set; }

    public int PeriodDay { get; set; }

    public string AlertStatus { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: It's unlikely to be a problem for the `UPDATE`, but you really should be using `Parameters.Add` not `Parameters.AddWithValue`. [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Can you share the Task class as well?

Comment: By reading the error, I think it might be a problem with the variable "@AlertStatus". Check your code and make sure you are setting it properly and that it is not NULL as this is probably the case. A very good way of finding the variable's value is using Console.Log(variable) just before the error ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward to solve for via divide and conquer.

Using Chrome, or whichever other browser, set a breakpoint on the line where you set task.Comment and inspect the task object to see if AlertStatus has a value at that point.  Then switch to the network tab, then continue stepping through the code.  Inspect the payload of the request sent to your controller and see if it also has AlertStatus in it.  If all that's good, then the problem is on the server side.  If not the problem is on your client side.

Then set a breakpoint in your controller in the beginning and inspect the task object for AlertStatus right there.  If its null, then something went wrong with the modelbinder.  If it has a value then you should be good at that point and the problem is somewhere after that.

Also, if you don't want to allow null for that value, you should do some validation before attempting to submit it to the database, and use the typical MVC validation elements to do so and return a 400 bad request back to the client.  Part of that validation may be in the Task class, which we cannot see at this time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, just had to change:

```
var task = {};
        task.taskID = row.find(".taskID").find("span").html();
        task.GroupSubsidiary = row.find(".GroupSub").find("span").html();
        task.FunctionName = row.find(".Fname").find("span").html();
        task.FunctionDesc = row.find(".Fdesc").find("span").html();
        task.CheckPeriod = row.find(".Checkp").find("span").html();
        task.Profiledate = row.find(".Pdate").find("span").html();
        task.PeriodDay = row.find(".Pday").find("span").html();
        task.AlertStatus = row.find(".Status").find("span").html();
        task.Comment = row.find(".Comment").find("span").html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateTask","Task")",
            data: '{task:' + JSON.stringify(task) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Updated Sucessfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("An Error Occured");
            }
        })
    });
```

To:

```
var task = JSON.stringify({
                taskID: row.find(".taskID").find("span").html(),
                GroupSubsidiary: row.find(".GroupSub").find("span").html(),
                FunctionName: row.find(".Fname").find("span").html(),
                FunctionDesc: row.find(".Fdesc").find("span").html(),
                CheckPeriod: row.find(".Checkp").find("span").html(),
                Profiledate: row.find(".Pdate").find("span").html(),
                PeriodDay: row.find(".Pday").find("span").html(),
                AlertStatus: row.find(".Status").find("input").val(),
                Comment: row.find(".Comment").find("span").html(),
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@Url.Action("UpdateTask","Task")",
                data:  task,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Updated Sucessfully");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An Error Occured");
                }
            });
            console.log(task);
        });
```